# TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null. Platform flash game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Now I'm having problems with my flash game especially going to level two. The problem started when I added the container for the locked door and the key. The game was in working condition like the sprites work, getting the key in level one works and unlocking it works. Trying for Level 2 becomes a pain. Help me please.

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.

```
at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
at TheHunterWithinv0_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/loop()
```

Comment: if(keyCollected == false){
   if(player.hitTestObject(back.doorKey)){
    back.doorKey.visible = false;
    keyCollected = true;
  }
 }
 if(doorOpen == false){ 
     if(keyCollected == true){ 
          if(player.hitTestObject(back.lockedDoor)){ 
              
               back.lockedDoor.gotoAndStop(2);
               doorOpen = true;
          }
     }
}

Comment: function nextLevel():void
{
 currentLevel++;
 trace("Next Level: " + currentLevel);
 if(currentLevel == 2){
  gotoLevel2();
 }
}
function gotoLevel2():void
{
 back.other.gotoAndStop(2);
 back.visuals.gotoAndStop(2);
 back.collisions.gotoAndStop(2);
 scrollX = 0;
 scrollY = 500;
 keyCollected = false;
 back.other.doorKey2.visible = true;
 doorOpen = false;
 back.other.lockedDoor2.gotoAndStop(1);
}

function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{

 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
  downPressed = true;
  if(doorOpen && player.hitTestObject(back.other.lockedDoor)){
   nextLevel();
  }
 } 
}

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code that you've added as comments.

Answer (score 2):

Error comes when object is removed from the stage, You should
check the reference of object you are passing in hittestobject.